# Is there a word in English that decribes a relief and rupture at the same time?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, meaning-in-context

In the Persian language, we have a word (گشایش)(goshayesh) that means both a rupture and a relief.
We use it when we want to say that from a breach in something, a new thing emerged, that is better than the first situation. 
clearly speaking, some intellectuals use this word to describe a revolution.
something has been destroyed and something new and more suitable has replaced it.
In these days I am translating an article into German (German is as  my mother tongue) and have had some problem with original text. The author is *like me*, not a native English speaker and has had a few poor word choices. For example, he has the word  **rupture** in this text, while it is not, in my view,  the most suitable word here. because it simply focuses on the breach of a harmonious situation and does not pay attention to a positive aspect of the case. Do know another word to use here?

> While there are a number of plausible labels that might be attached to the 20th century, in terms of social history it was clearly the age of the working class. For the first time, working people who lacked property became a major and sustained political force. This **rupture** was heralded by Pope Leo xiii—leader of the world’s oldest and largest social organization—in his encyclical Rerum Novarum in 1891. The Pope noted that the progress of industry had led to ‘the accumulation of affluence among the few and misery (inopia) among the multitude’; but the period had also been characterized by the ‘greater self-confidence and tighter cohesion’ of the workers. [1] On a global level, trade unions gained a foothold in most big industrial enterprises, and in many other firms too. Working-class parties became major electoral forces—sometimes dominant ones—in Europe and its Australasian offshoots. The October Revolution in Russia provided a model of political organization and social change for China and Vietnam. Nehru’s India set itself the avowed goal of following a ‘socialist pattern of development’, as did the majority of post-colonial states. Many African countries spoke of building ‘working-class parties’ when they could boast no more proletarians than would fill a few classrooms.

Comment: Could you describe it as '[bittersweet](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bittersweet)'?

Comment: yes , but not exactly .As you know , in the case of revolution , the situation is always  bitter for a part of people and sweet for other part . I describe it as bitter-sweet when i speak of the whole society , but not when I express and translate a special view of point . this event is for a person  either pleasant or unpleasant.

Comment: I  have tried my utmost to explain what  I need and unfortunately can not add any explanation

Comment: Is there also a word in German for this? Or is that your final goal and you're trying to get there through English? Or what?

Comment: I do not know such a word in German . I think  the author  has intended to express the concept of  (goshayesh) . but he has been not able to find the best word . perhaps  there is not  such a word in English too .

Comment: I have say that German is as my mother tongue and I can understand an equivalent for this word in German

Comment: Perhaps you might consider getting a bit more metaphoric - you could call the process ***lancing of the boil***.

Comment: FumbleFingers@yes.that is what I exactly mean . but , as you know, we can use this word in an academic text .besides I need a single word not a phrase. however , thank you for expressing my intention in the best way.

Comment: @Pedram if, as you say, you can 'understand an equivalent or this word in German' then what exactly is that equivalent in German? I'm asking because there may well be a phrase for it in English but giving what you know in German could give more hints to us.

Comment: As you say, "revolution" seems close. Looking at that in a thesaurus, how about **reformation** or **about-face**? I was also thinking of **catharsis**.

Comment: "Decribes"?????

Comment: In the paragraph you included in your question, the word "evolution" would work well. While evolution does not always result in something better than what existed before--in which case de-volution would be the appropriate word, the process you describe seems to be evolving for the betterment of humankind. Don

Comment: Social upheaval; break with the past?

Comment: If you really want a word that embodies those two ideas, I'd probably say "catharsis". However, in the context of that paragraph, I think that something like "development" or "transformation" would work better.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any *word* that conveys this meaning. There are some idioms that apply, although they somewhat hinge on what you specifically mean.

> **[There's no rose without a thorn.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/There%27s+no+rose+without+a+thorn)**
>   [**It's always darkest before the dawn.**](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/darkest-hour.html)

These idioms apply if the "rupture" is *intentional* (and/or *necessary*) to achieve the "relief".

> [**A happy accident**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+happy+accident)

This seems to fit better if you are trying to say that the "rupture" was started (for a different reason, or no particular reason), and only later ended up causing (unexpected) "relief".

I can't think of a better example for the second case.

---

**edit**

A somewhat looser definition of the second case could be **[serendipity](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/serendipity)**:

> The occurrence and development of events by chance in a happy or beneficial way.

**However**, serendipity inherently means that it was based on **luck**. If you are trying to imply that the "rupture" and "relief" are a logical cause and effect (not just two random coincidental events, they are connected), then "serendipity" does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on the part of the passage with the word "rupture":

> "For the first time, working people who lacked property became a major and sustained political force. This ***rupture*** was heralded by Pope Leo xiii—leader of the world’s oldest and largest social organization—in his encyclical Rerum Novarum in 1891."

Rupture is clearly the wrong word because implies something that is painful and problematic, which we can assume doesn't apply to working people getting more political power.  It's a bit too medical, as well, I think.

"Revolution" is a better word, but is too strong, and is too easily confused with a literal political revolution, where the workers (for example) actually revolt and seize power.  This isn't what is being talked about here.

"Movement" is one option but again might imply too much organisation, making the reader think of something more specific, with a name, like an "-ism", rather than something more general and organic.

"Trend" is another option, and describes it in neutral terms.

"[Upheaval](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/upheaval)" is perhaps a better option, as it implies a major change which will probably affect all existing structures in some way.  It's similar to rupture in that it can be used to describe earthquakes and volcanoes, but I think it fits better than "rupture" when talking about social change.

I think I'd go with upheaval.  It doesn't necessarily convey the "both good and bad" that you asked for, but it fits the context, and upheavals are understood to often have positive and negative aspects.

Answer (score 1):

I expand on the elegant typology offered by Max Williams by suggesting that a further replacement for Rupture is "Disruption".

Although there are traditional definitions (e.g. *disturbance or problems which interrupt an event, activity, or process* https://www.google.com.au/search?rls=en&q=define+disruption) the word "Disruption" is developing an extended meaning because of its use in marketing. Today a disruptive product is one that meets the needs of a market segment because *an incumbent in the market finds it almost impossible to respond to a disruptive product*. Consider Tesla's rise vs General Motors, who crushed their first EV saying it didn't fit their business model. Perhaps the Pope is arguing that the **Disruption** had the potential to be a positive force for the un-propertied working people.

In a new-market disruption, *the unserved customers are unserved precisely because serving them would be unprofitable given the incumbent’s business model* (Prof. Clay Christensen, Harvard Business School, in 'The Innovator’s Dilemma').

Arguably - even though this is not about marketing - this word DOES seem to now convey some of the 'both good and bad' aspects sought by the question.

Comment: ( Perhaps the Pope is arguing that the Disruption had the potential to be a positive force for the un-propertied working people.). That is exactly what Pope means. you know what come from the rupture to mind is not positive . we would not understand the message of Pope , If we did not have previous historical knowledge.so what I need is more suitable word to express a good and bad accident ?

Comment: You should add a link/reference to a dictionary definition of _disruption_ (in the relevant sense). Perhaps then you may get up-votes.

Answer (score 1):

> We use it when we want to say that from a breach in something, a new thing emerged, that is better than the first situation.

Focussing on this part of your description, I would suggest [metamorphosis](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/metamorphosis).

To me, this signifies both the destruction of the old order and the birth of the new [improved] situation.

Answer (score 1):

In English, in historical texts, one often sees: this break with the past. Not rupture. Rupture suggests that the situation has boiled over or broken out (like a boil). And in English, we also often say a welcome break from the past. Not just a single word. Often, the simplest solution is best....

Other suggestions such as revolution, upheaval etc. are too heavy to convey the meaning you are searching for.

Idioms: break with or from the past, welcome break from the past, welcome break with the past.

[Reference](http:////scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&q=Pope%20Leo%20XIII%20%2B%20welcome%20break%20from%20the%20past])

"Pope Leo makes a break with the Christian Fathers that is profound."

in Social Catholicism in Europe: From the Onset of Industrialization to the First World War
[Book](http:////scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&q=Pope%20Leo%20XIII%20%2B%20welcome%20break%20from%20the%20past])

Answer (score 1):

A major change that involves massive disruption followed by relief could be called a **tectonic change** or **tectonic shift**, though in the case of the text cited in the question, I would simply recommend the word **shift**.

> While there are a number of plausible labels that might be attached to the 20th century, in terms of social history it was clearly the age of the working class. For the first time, working people who lacked property became a major and sustained political force. This **shift** was heralded by Pope Leo xiii

From [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/tectonic):

> A **tectonic change** is a very important one that will have major effects:
>
> *He led the company through a period of **tectonic shifts** in the movie industry.*
>
> *The process of writing is in the midst of a **tectonic change** caused by changes in the technology writers use.*

And simply *shift*:

> **8.f.** To undergo transmutation; to change.

- *OED*

Comment: BEST OFFER yet. but do you think we can use these compounds in a political text ?

Comment: @kazhvan Is that a joke?

Comment: WHAT is a joke?

Answer (score 0):

In medicine a boil, pimple or similar pustule of the skin is relieved once ruptures and its contents are emitted. the pustule is said to "Express" its contents. That is the natural process of the skin.

Express is the word you need but may not be well understood by your audience.

Comment: Welcome to SE EL&U. Nice answer Elliot! All it needs for SE EL&U is a link to an online dictionary definition that backs it up, preferably with a quotation for that particular meaning. This may seem a bit tedious to newcomers, but, if you think about it, you should appreciate that it allows the poster and others to check your answer. It would be a good idea to complete the [guided tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better idea of how this site works to help with future questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

A single word to signify *rupture* and *release* in a cultural historical context could be 'inflection'.

To signify both *rupture* and *release* in a word is a tall order since these words would ordinarily contradict each other. Persian is a much older language; perhaps English is not yet complete with this subtle concept. Previous answers tried to say it with what seems to be a lack of success.

Its a hard one all right.

The word 'inflection' has an historical ring to it
implying the end of an order, the birth of a new one.
I think 'inflection' works well in the test sentence.

in·​flec·​tion | \ in-ˈflek-shən  \

Definition of inflection

1: change in pitch or loudness of the voice

2a: the change of form that words undergo to mark such distinctions as those of case, gender, number, tense, person, mood, or voice

b: a form, suffix, or element involved in such variation

c: ACCIDENCE

3: the act or result of curving or bending : BEND

4a: change in curvature of an arc or curve from concave to convex or conversely

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inflection

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please cite the sources you reference.

Comment: The ages of the languages are irrelevant; both ultimately descend from PIE. Over the centuries, English has acquired many new words, giving it a notoriously large lexis. If it lacks a particular word, the reason is almost certainly not because of its age or lack of "completeness".

Comment: If English lacks a word to express a concept that can be said in a single word in Persian. this suggests that there may be a subtle concept that are the English language has difficulty signifying.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it would seem English doesn't have such a useful word.

May I suggest **rebirth** or perhaps a synonym like **revival** or **renewal**?

While it doesn't capture the same nuance a word such as **disruption** in replacement of rupture would sound okay too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).